# Set division by 0 to return 0

Tags: oracle, plsql, divide-by-zero

It occurred to me that PL/SQL might have a more concise way of doing this:

I have a program where division-by-zero can occur, but in all cases I want this to return 0. My current logic looks like:

```
if bar <> 0 then
    foobar := foo/bar;
else
    foobar := 0;
end if;
```

Does anyone know of an easier/cheaper way to do this ? I'm fairly new to PL/SQL and I saw that I could use an exception handler, but that appears to skip the operation. So I think I could make an exception for `zero_divide` and then just do:

```
foobar := 0;
foobar := foo/bar;
```

I worry that isn't as easy to follow, though. Thanks for any insight!

Comment: yeah I see no problem with using the logic you have.

Comment: Division by 0 is not defined, so correct solution would be `foobar := foo/NULLIF(bar,0);`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit : That is why I am asking this question; I specifically want this to return 0 instead of a mathematically correct result :P

Comment: Well, you could wrap the expression with a `coalesce` or `nvl`, e.g. `nvl(foo/nullif(bar,0),0)` - however, the `case` suggestions below seem neater.

Comment: Oh, but that's clever. I honestly find that more readable (I like function notation).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following:

```sql
declare
  foo    integer := 1;
  bar    integer := 0;
  foobar integer;
begin
  foobar := case bar when 0 then 0 else foo/bar end;
  dbms_output.put_line(foobar);  
end;
```

Output:

```
0
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `CASE`?

```
foobar = case when bar = 0 then 0
              else foo/bar
         end;
```

Comment: Thanks, I see you were the first to suggest this approach. I didn't know about `CASE` or how to use it; this is a great example and I'll be able to apply it to future (and past!) problems :)

Answer (score 2):

You can handle it with `exception` also.

```
BEGIN
   foobar := foo/bar;
EXCEPTION 
   WHEN ZERO_DIVIDE THEN
      foobar := 0;
END;
/
```

Comment: I had considered this approach, but it seems more convoluted in this particular case. I'll keep this in mind as I encounter future exceptions :) So just to be clear, this means that I could add a custom exception after any block that might cause an exception? (I ask because in my current case, I would have to do this for a bunch of different variables). In one language I know, exceptions can actually override the output. For example, when `foo/bar` throws an exception, your handler can return 0, then the assignment would use 0 as the result.